# Count Minutes Between Current Time and Open Time

Tags: sql, time, count, between

I have a auxiliary table as

> Time                                  Minute
>   2013-01-01 09:00:00.000    1
>   2013-01-01 09:01:00.000    1
>   2013-01-01 09:02:00.000    1
>   2013-01-01 09:03:00.000    1
>   2013-01-01 09:04:00.000    1
>   2013-01-01 09:05:00.000    1

(Time range is for every day between 09 and 17).

The next table looks like as follows

> ID    OPEN_TIME                         TITLE      SLA
>   1    2012-12-17 11:46:47.000     AAA 
>   2    2012-12-18 09:33:18.000     BBB 
>   3    2012-12-18 13:14:02.000     CCC 
>   4    2012-12-19 14:23:53.000     DDD 
>   5    2013-01-03 07:48:11.000     EEE

How to count number of minutes from the first table in time interval / range between "current time (systime)" and "OPEN_TIME"? 
+ the result (count / sum of minutes) should be added into column SLA afterwards for each record.

Is there any possible solution? (SQL Server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use following function for get minute difference.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,opentime,endtime);
```

Please refer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Well, the MySQL function will not really help me on SQL Server, will it? Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL Server** datediff will do your job, for example

```
SELECT datediff(mi,'2012-12-17 11:46:47.000' , '2012-12-17 11:47:47.000')
```

this will display 1 since there is a minute difference between two intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you need a a function to add minutes to an escalation time, but only during working hours.

You could calculate your minutes from your first table by using something like

```
Select SUM(Minute) from auxiliary  where Time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The following function will do that, skipping any time that's outside @SCStartHours and @SCEndHours. And also outside Saturday and Sunday:

The function would be used like so:

Adding 60 "working minutes" to an OPEN_TIME:

```
select AddWorkingMinutes(OPEN_TIME, 60, 9,17)


    create Function AddWorkingMinutes(@EscalateOnDate datetime, @escalationminutes int, 

@SCStartHours int, @SCEndHours int)
returns datetime
as
begin

declare @workminutesperday int = (@SCEndHours - @SCStartHours)*60
declare @workdays int = @escalationminutes/@workminutesperday
declare @minutes int = @escalationminutes - @workminutesperday * @workdays


-- If the date falls out of hours then move it forward to the next earliest period
while DATENAME(weekday, @EscalateOnDate ) = 'Saturday' 
      OR DATENAME(weekday, @EscalateOnDate ) = 'Sunday'
      OR DATEPART(hour, @EscalateOnDate ) >= @SCEndHours
begin
set @EscalateOnDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@EscalateOnDate )
set @EscalateOnDate = DATEADD(hh,@SCStartHours,DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, @EscalateOnDate )))
end
while  DATEPART(hour,@EscalateOnDate ) < @SCStartHours
begin
set @EscalateOnDate = DATEADD(hh,@SCStartHours,DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, @EscalateOnDate )))
end

--now check if we have enough minutes in the day remaining, if not add a day and take the remaining minutes off.
declare @minutesremaining int = DATEDIFF(minute, @EscalateOnDate , DATEADD(hh,@SCEndHours,DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, @EscalateOnDate ))))
if @minutesremaining < @minutes
begin
set @minutes = @minutes - @minutesremaining
set @workdays = @workdays + 1
set @EscalateOnDate = DATEADD(hh,@SCStartHours,DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, @EscalateOnDate )))
end

return DATEADD(minute,@minutes,DATEADD(day, (@workdays % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, @EscalateOnDate ) + (@workdays % 5)) % 7)
                                                 WHEN 0 THEN 2
                                                 WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                 ELSE 0 END, DATEADD(week, (@workdays / 5), @EscalateOnDate )))
end
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try it out and let you know. You have done great job, appreciate your time!